# Where is the IndexCounter in db.serverStatus() on MongoDB 3.0

Tags: performance, mongodb, monitoring

I saw `idx` miss % in mongostat but when I run

```
db.serverStatus().indexCounters
```

there is no response. where can I find this? And One more question, what is the appropriate page fault value I should concern?

Comment: You could try `db.stats().indexes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `indexCounters` information was specific to MMAP storage and not entirely accurate (for some examples, see: [SERVER-9296](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9296), [SERVER-9284](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9284), and [SERVER-14583](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14583)). The `indexCounters` section was removed during the development cycle leading up to MongoDB 3.0 along with some other former metrics like `recordStats` and `workingSet`. See: [SERVER-16378](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16378) and discussion on related issues in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker.

If you have enabled the WiredTiger storage engine, note that there will be a new `wiredTiger` section in the `serverStatus()` output with relevant metrics.

> what is the appropriate page fault value I should concern?

Page faults provide a good proxy for whether your working set fits in memory with MMAP, but the specific value of concern will depend on your deployment and whether there is any noticeable performance impact. Consistently high hard page faults (where data needs to be loaded from disk to RAM) will add I/O pressure, but this may not be significant depending on your disk configuration and overall workload.

A general best practice is to use a monitoring system like [MMS (MongoDB Management Service)](http://mms.mongodb.com/) to capture a historical baseline of metrics for your deployment so you can then look for pain points when performance problems are observed.

It's also worth reading the [Production Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) section of the MongoDB manual. If you are using Linux, for example, there are some suggestions on tuning file system and readahead parameters that can affect the efficiency of reading data from disk.

For an idea of how to approach metrics, see: [Five MMS monitoring alerts to keep your MongoDB deployment on track](http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/five-mms-monitoring-alerts-keep-your-mongodb-deployment-track). This blog post is a few years old but the general approach of determining normal, worrying, and critical limits (as well as identifying false positives) is still very relevant.

Comment: Thank you ! This is very helpful for me. I have another question. How to see the lock% in MongoDB 3.0?